# When store config in .js file and when store it in .json file?

Tags: javascript, json, config

I am building a nodejs app that need some config.

I want to know when I have to use .json file and when use .js file

my .js file config is:

```
module.exports = {
     providers : "http://localhost:8545",
     account : 0,
};
```

or in json file:

```
{
   "providers": "http://localhost:8545",
   "account": 0
}
```

Comment: Why you should store configuration in a javascript? JSON is a valid format for data exchange.

Comment: I am asking why not ?

Comment: That is optinionbased. But I would go for JSON, because I only want to have primitive data types in my config file and not the possiblity that there is code in it that is executed.